# Getting file and folder issues using htaccess file in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working for a blog system using PHP PDO. I have created a post.php page in my root folder. In the same root, I have an Admin folder.
I am getting posts from databases like -

```
example.com/cat_slug/post_slug
```

i.e

```
example.com/php/how-to-learn-php
```

As you can see there is no post keyword in the URL because of the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On  
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ post.php?cat=$1&postSlug=$2 [L]
```

It's correct according to my need but in the same folder, I have the Admin folder(where post.php is located ). The Admin folder contains folders and files. Now, when I open the Admin folder it's going to post.php

like -

```
example.com/Admin
```

and it's going to example.com/Admin and output -
undefine - slug ad cat.
I want to that when I visit the Admin folder it should open Admin files not redirect to the post.php file. I have many folders in my root same as Admin. All are going to post.php execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ post.php?cat=$1&postSlug=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I have an issue again. I have created another learn.php page and redirecting like example.com/learn/php for list view using this htaccess code  `RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^learn/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ learn.php?cat_list=$1 [L]`  but its also redirection on post.php . Its another page . learn.php  . I want to example.com/learn/php

Comment: Order of rules in .htaccess file are important. Most acurate rules should be first, maybe that is your problem now? Try to write rule for learn.php before post.php.